# Access denied to user MySQL Java Openshift

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, openshift

I am using Openshift and installed Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) and Mysql 5.5. My application is based on Struts 2 where i have provided database connectivity details in struts.xml. now after giving details like host and password. it still not able to  connect. 
i have two concerns.

1-- How to debug when using the deployed application. I can see the log but its not detailed. both the application and database in is openshift and have added catridge of  Jboss and mysql. is it sufficient??

2.-- How to use openshift db from  my locally deployed application. it says unable to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set up a JNDI data source in JBOSS instead of using Struts for connectivity.  Struts is web MVC.

Comment: You need a data source XML configuration in your JBOSS instance: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-datasource/jboss-datasource-configuration

Comment: OK.   Done that. But how to use the Openshift installed DB. still facing same issue.

Comment: checkout this [kb](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1076-default-database-connectivity-configurations-for-jboss-applications)

Comment: java.sql.SQLException
MESSAGE: Access denied for user 'adminWr65TNK'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Done. i was overriding the context.xml settings

Comment: how did u solve this? i am facing similar issue using spring mvc

Comment: Please ask your own question.  This one is > 2 years old.